# Find maximum value in array for a given temperature range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Study   Gas Surfactant  Surfactant Concentration    Additive    Additive 

Concentration   LiquidPhase Quality Pressure (Psi)  Temperature (C)     Shear Rate (/Sec)   Halflife (Min)  Viscosity   Color
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   51  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   61  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   75  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   105 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   12  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   25  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   34  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   48  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.1 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.5 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.79    0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    None    None    DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.9 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   26  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   72  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   84  0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  50  0   120 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.33    0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   1   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   1.9 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   2.4 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.2 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   1   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   1.3 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   1.9 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.1 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.2 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.26    0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  100 0   0.3 0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  150 0   0   0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  150 0   0.05    0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  150 0   0.08    0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  150 0   0.13    0   yellow
Thakore 2020    N2  AOS 1 w%    Guar    0.36 w% DI Water    0.95    10  150 0   0.2 0   yellow
```

Shown above is a sample of my array. How would I find the maximum value of "Halflife" for a given temperature? Say I wanted to find the maximum value of "Halflife" out of every element that has a temperature of 25 degrees. Is there an elegant way to do this?

I have tried looping through in a `for` loop, splitting the temperatures into separate lists, then using a lot of of `if` statements, finding the max of each list and compiling it back into a master-list. This was very ugly and time consuming, I wonder if there is a better way to do it. Please let me know!

Basically I load the excel file into a pandas dataframe here:

```
dv = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Then I clean it up and rename it to "cleaned" which is not important, just mentioning.

```
ahmed17 = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Ahmed 2017"]
ahmed18 = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Ahmed 2018"]
alzo = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Alzobaidi 2017"]
reid = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Reidenbach 1986"]
har = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Harris 1987"]
chen = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Chen, Y. 2016b"]
yan = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Yanqing Wang 2017"]
hut = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Hutchins 2005"]
tha = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Thakore 2020"]
ha = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Harris 1995"]
```

From there, I separate the cleaned dataframe into separate studies, this project is a composition of literature.

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(y=ahmed17[selected_y], x=ahmed17[selected_x])
```

Finally, I load each of the individual studies into traces, and display them in a graph. Selected y and selected x are strings, such as "Temperature (C) " and "Halflife (Min)".

What I need to do is, prior to splitting the array into individual studies, find the maximum "Halflife" relative to each temperature (0,50,100,150,200,250,300) and compile them into separate lists, then compile them into the same list. From there I can split the list into separate studies, and I am good to go. I have tried to do this using stuff like:

```
tha25 = [x for x in tha[selected_x] if x == 25]
```

To split the thakore study into a 25 degree list, then find the max from there. But I got a bunch of Nan values for the list I compiled, and I am unsure if I am splitting the list correctly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Could you post some codes, that you have already- what exactly did you try? Also - what technology are you using? Can you also put your data in writing, possibly together with desired output?

Comment: By the way, I'd just load this csv into a dataframe, group by temperature, then find max halflife for each group.

Comment: I deleted all of my prior code, but I will try to find some to show what I have done. I will post what I am working with, it is using plotly-dash software

Comment: Please do. Is that image really needed to run your test code with? It's of no use for people trying to help you (apart from painstakingly re-typing it), so try to include all (relevant only) data as well.

Comment: I will add a study from the data as well

Comment: I attempted to add the data to use, let me know if it does not paste well into excel etc

Answer (score 0):

If your original, cleaned dataframe is df then try this:

```
(df[df['Temperature']==25])['Halflife'].max()
```